# Using DateTime Variable In Where Clause

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I am trying to pull all data where a sale date is >= to a certain datetime.  When I execute my query I get an error of:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 15
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

What should I alter to get his query operational?
Below is sample DDL

```
Declare @datetime datetime = GetDate(), @sql varchar(max)

Create Table #dinonuggets
(
  saledate datetime
  ,item varchar(500)
)

Insert Into #dinonuggets Values
('2016-03-30 12:02:00.000','chair')
,('2016-03-04 08:12:48.000','stove')
,('2016-03-07 09:37:39.000','washer')


Set @sql = 'Select * FROM #dinonuggets WHERE saledate >= '+@datetime+' '
Print @sql
Exec (@sql)
```

My expected output would be 

03/30/2016 12:02:00.000 chair 

 as that is the only data that meets the criteria

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your issue relates to the way you are building your dynamic SQL. If you look at the output from your PRINT statement, there are no quotes around your `@datetime`.  Additionally, selecting from a #temp table within dynamic SQL isn't going to do what you want it to do. `#dynonuggets` is going to be out-of-scope for your dynamic SQL. If you really do need to work with a dynamic table, you'll need to make a [global temporary table](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186986(v=sql.105).aspx), named `##dynonuggets`.

I'll assume, `DynoNuggets` is a real table, and you have to use dynamic SQL, and your example is just simplified for your question.

You could add quotes, but the more appropriate solution is to [use sp_executesql to parameterize your dynamic SQL](http://am2.co/2015/01/sp_executesql-with-output-parameters/).

Try this:

```
DECLARE @datetime datetime = GETDATE(), 
        @sql nvarchar(max),
        @params nvarchar(1000)

CREATE TABLE DinoNuggets
(
  saledate datetime
  ,item varchar(500)
)

INSERT INTO DinoNuggets VALUES
('2016-03-30 12:02:00.000','chair')
,('2016-03-04 08:12:48.000','stove')
,('2016-03-07 09:37:39.000','washer')

SET @sql = N'SELECT * FROM DinoNuggets WHERE saledate >= @ParamValue';
SET @Params = N'@ParamValue datetime';
PRINT @sql;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql, @params, @ParamValue = @datetime
```

Answer (score -3):

Declare the `@datetime` as a `datetime2`.

Then alter the `@sql` query to:-

```
Set @sql = 'Select * FROM #dinonuggets WHERE saledate >= ''' + cast( @datetime as varchar(23)) + ''' '
```

This will get around the date formating issue as well as allowing the correct string concatenation.
Without the `cast` you would receive this error:-

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1
>   The data types varchar and datetime2 are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: Why use the `datetime2` type if CAST alone resolves the issue?

Comment: Casting to varchar to include as a string in dynamic SQL means that when the dynamic SQL runs, it has to do an implicit conversion back to datetime in order to query #DinoNuggets. Best to just parameterize the dynamic SQL and use sp_executesql.